# I want to use max where field name=something

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use max clause to find the maximum value according to field name
Till now i had used this

```
SELECT MAX(sl) FROM associate where br_code=$_REQUEST[br_code]
```

but this isn't worked

Friend as from my question it is clear that i want to find the max value of the sl from a group of br_code name which should be selected from the where clause.

Comment: What result do you get? You should avoid using $_REQUEST because of security reasons (use $_PSOT and $_GET instead).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: I give you that the question is a bit naive, but it still is a question and it's valid. I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selects your data, while being secure from SQL Injection attacks.

```
$query = "SELECT mx FROM (SELECT MAX(s1) AS mx, br_code FROM associate GROUP BY br_code) AS T1 WHERE T1.br_code=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['br_code']);
```

Please **note** that when using `mysql_real_escape_string` you have to already have an established connection. See [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for more information.

Comment: Maybe that's because `br_code` is a string field, in which case you should change it into this: "...br_code=\"" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['br_code']) . '"';

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. Then you should mark this question as solved by selecting the correct answer. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for more information.

Comment: hI MILIND i am not allowed to ask question further pls vote up my question so that i can ask more in future